# Correct Format for DefaultTreeSelectionModel.addSelectionPaths()

Tags: java, checkbox, jtree

I'm working with a class that extends the DefaultTreeSelectionModel to create a CheckBoxTree. When clicking a checkbox node on the tree it fires a MouseEvent which gets the TreePath directly from the JTree ("tree").

```
TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
```

This "path" is passed into the DefaultTreeSelectionModel.addSelectionPath() function and the appropriate CheckBoxes are selected. So far so good!

What I'd like to do is pass my own TreePath into DefaultTreeSelectionModel.addSelectionPath() but so far I'm having issues with the format of the TreePath which seems to differ from the TreePath I get from the code above because it doesn't have the same effect; and that is my problem.

When I click the CheckBox (the way that works) the TreePath printout is "[/, Documents and Settings, Administrator]", but to simulate that I'd have to create a TreePath like:

```
File[] finalPath = new File[3];
finalPath[0] = (File)parentNode; // parentNode is the root from the Model
finalPath[1] = new File("Documents and Settings");
finalPath[2] = new File("Administrator");
TreePath path = new TreePath(finalPath);
```

... which doesn't work because index 1 and 2 don't reference the root, but it does printout as "[/, Documents and Settings, Administrator]" like the working click method.

So then I tried:

```
File[] finalPath = new File[3];
finalPath[0] = (File)parentNode; // parentNode is the root from the Model
finalPath[1] = new File(finalPath[0],"Documents and Settings");
finalPath[2] = new File(finalPath[1],"Administrator");
TreePath path = new TreePath(finalPath);
```

... which leaves the "parentNode" selected and "Administrator" selected, but not "Documents and Settings". The printout is "[/, /Documents and Settings, /Documents and Settings/Administrator]"

So I figured, it must be processing all three parts as separate selections such that anything that appears an odd number of times will stay selected and that's why "Documents and Settings" didn't stick. So, I tried simply.

```
File[] finalPath = new File[1];
finalPath[0] = new File(parentNode+"Documents and Settings"+File.separator+"Administrator");
TreePath path = new TreePath(finalPath);
```

... which doesn't select anything. The printout is "[\Documents and Settings\Administrator]"

So after about, I donno, 5 hours of trying various permutations the ones above are the closest I came to getting it and now I'm posting my issue here in hopes of a response. 
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Have you printed what the instances are in the TreePath that you get when you click? Sounds odd that it should be a path of File instances, instead of TreeNode, but I guess you have changed something when you subclassed.

Comment: TreePath can take an array of objects during its instantiation. How do I figure out what an existing TreePath was made from?

Comment: Furthermore, how do I create a TreeNode to put into my TreePath; it is an abstract class.

Comment: Also, I should note that although I'm using a subclass but ultimately it works by calling super.addSelectionPath(). "Super" is the DefaultTreeSelectionModel so whatever works there should work here.

Comment: You can either use a debugger to check the instance, or add some printing like System.out.println(treepath.getClass()) or treepath[0].getClass() or whatever it is that you have.

Comment: The treepath when clicking is a TreePath which is what is returned from tree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY()); TreePaths can be instantiated from an Object[], but I still don't see how to find out what type of Object that was. Thanks

Comment: `System.out.println(treePath.getPath()[0].getClass())` will print the type of the path element.

Comment: Ok. That worked. The TreePath is made of "java.oi.File".

Comment: So you should in that case be able to construct an identical copy?